# How is TS able to resolve infinitely recursive type correctly?

Tags: typescript

Recently I wrote a type that replaces all booleans and numbers in an object with strings.

```
type AllStrings<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]:
        T[Key] extends number
            ? string
            : T[Key] extends boolean
            ? string
            : AllStrings<T[Key]>;
}
```

What I do not understand, why is it working correctly without an edge case like `T[Key] extends string ? string : AllStrings<T[Key]>`.

If I use this type like so:

```
interface Person { name: string }
type NewPerson = AllStrings<Person>
```

Why does not it go into an infinite loop? Why TS understands that `name` in `NewPerson` is a `string`? Is this behavior documented somewhere? Is it intended or will be possible that it breaks with another version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it work without an edge case (filter) ?

When mapping over `Person`, the `AllStrings` type will also go over `name: string` and determine that it is neither a `number` nor a `boolean`. It will then call itself with `AllStrings<string>`. You might assume that execution will continue here since the `string` type also has lots of properties to map over. But in fact, mapping over *primitive* types will just evaluate to the *primitve* itself. You can read about that in the (lesser known) TypeScript-[FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#common-bugs-that-arent-bugs).

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#common-bugs-that-arent-bugs):

> Mapped types declared as { [ K in keyof T ]: U } where T is a type parameter are known as homomorphic mapped types, which means that the mapped type is a structure preserving function of T. When type parameter T is instantiated with a primitive type the mapped type evaluates to the same primitive.

So `AllStrings<string>` just evaluates to `string` which ends the recursion.

> Will be possible that it breaks with another version?

This will *likely* not break in another version. But be aware that your type breaks in other scenarios. Imagine you are passing a `Person` with a `Date` property.

```
interface Person { name: Date }

type NewPerson = AllStrings<Person>
```

`Date` is not a primitve so the mapped type will map over the `Date` and will replace all the `number` and `boolean` properties. TypeScript does not do us a favor in properly displaying the type here. But you can check what happens when you pass a `Date` to `AllStrings`.

```
type NewPerson2 = AllStrings<Date>
// type NewPerson2 = {
//     toString: AllStrings<() => string>;
//     toDateString: AllStrings<() => string>;
//     toTimeString: AllStrings<() => string>;
//     toLocaleString: AllStrings<{
//         (): string;
//         (locales?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined, options?: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string;
//     }>;
//     ... 40 more ...;
//     [Symbol.toPrimitive]: AllStrings<...>;
// }
```

Mapping recursively through a `Date` and changing its types is probably not what your type was intended to do.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnAysATgSwHYHMDOAeAFQD4oBeKAbwCgpaoBtAaQhCkygGsWB7AMygIBdAFw064gkxaCoEAB7AIGACY4oGAK4BbAEYQUY8UagB%20KDlSYsh43WECpIGfMUq1O7tzgQAhhhu2puaW2AG29vBIIbiEjoJEANxUAL5UVJiKKLw%20AMbQAAr6ONwYlOo%20WhD2ACI%20ilCpVKCQUAByEADuhSjFpeSRyOjY%20N29RE3g0O1dRSUATGSwCINW%20LWK4wD0m1DNU52j84vU20bA3CvYEcvR%20AAUAJRkJBZDWIlUp%20Ln6xCXWNcom97k9SC9oh8vnRzgQ0JV-oD-iDnsE3pCdt9uAAZbg5HzeBFLIGrPAnDG2R72V5WJJQ4x3OC4-EQHAmKnRKAAHygADo%20VAAIxQLTcFDQPk8rlQDQqCC8TAQZQAGig3DAwDQJVZ9gAkhhgHAeb9YZUAGKirR1ADy6s1GDU3JlyjlCuUD3Zb1p5NoyXRRglUAALAAGYWi8V8r1GeiIEC6Lw8875dBaNAagBuEBERKReAlfuSQA)

Comment: Thank you! I am not concerned about `Date`, 'cause I get my `Person` from a JSON string. But it's an interesting point!